# Docker: How to connect to locally available servers from within docker

Tags: docker, networking

I run docker on windows. I have a docker container running a python application that needs a database connection.

Installing a DB on my machine and connecting to it via "docker.for.win.localhost" in my container works fine.

Now I want to connect to a database running on a server that is available over my local network. I can't seem to connect to it from inside my docker container. I don't quite understand how I can proxy the server to my container. The error indicates that it can't establish a connection to this server:

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No route to host
        Is the server running on host "XX.XXX.XX.XX" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5555?
```

I'm sure this is supposed to work somehow, right?

Answer (score -1):

you can add IP of host to the container

```
docker run --add-host="yourhost:IPOFTHEHOST"
```

and yourhost will be connected to host

Comment: `localhost` is very specifically defined to be 127.0.0.1 (or ::1 in IPv6) and it has a fairly specific meaning, Internet-wide.  Setting it to something else is likely to cause unexpected problems.

Comment: @DavidMaze it's just an example for better understanding